# Mac FileSync project is null when attempting filesync

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin

I have been running filesync to hotswap my js,html, and css files for my project. It seems to work at random times and not work at random times. I have removed all filesync setups, built and deployed to my local. Filesync will then still work at random times. Sometimes it will push my js,html, and css changes and sometimes i get this error after both times.

How do i fix this so i am able to hotswap my files? cleaning my local server and then restarting it for a simple change is time consuming and annoying.

```
Could not run FileSync builder - project is null!
```

---

metaData/.log

```
!ENTRY de.loskutov.FileSync 4 0 2015-03-02 10:36:30.072
!MESSAGE Could not run FileSync builder - project is null!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!MESSAGE Could not run FileSync builder - project is null!
```

This means that the project was not selected.

You need to select the project in Eclipse by clicking on it in the package explorer view. Then you can run the File Synchronization.